# Проблема с классами после создания Maven проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Привет, на Java я новичок, делала проект изначально без Maven, потом решила сделать из него Maven проект (учусь как), добавила в корень `pom.xml`, в Intellij Idea указала, что хочу сделать его maven проектом, и вот проблема - после этого классы как будто не видят друг друга. До этого работало нормально, все запускалось. И  что самое странное в `Edit Configurations` не видит класса Main в модуле проекта. Заранее благодарю за ответы.

P.S. Содержание `pom.xml`, после идет описание локального репозитория и зависимостей. Сам файл лежит в той же папке, что и src. Класс Main в папке `src/main/java`, а в подпапках и рядом с `Main.java` еще есть другие классы, которые используют друг друга. Так вот они друг друга и не видят. И еще не находит метод main в `main.java.Main`

```
 <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>
                                <packageName>main.java</packageName>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: Пальцем в небо: проверьте, где лежат ваши исходники. По умолчанию Maven будет искать их в папке `src/main/java` (относительный путь от `pom.xml`). А вообще, добавьте в вопрос больше информации о вашей проблеме (расположение исходников, содержимое `pom.xml`, сообщения об ошибках), попытайтесь создать [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ой извините, вот содержание pom.xml

Comment: Закройте IDEA, удалите директорию `.idea` в корне проекта и импортируйте проект в IDEA, как Maven проект.

Comment: <artifactId> должен быть указан название вашего проекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по `<mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>`, вы решили, что папки `main/java` являются частью иерархии пакетов. Нет, они не являются. В проектах Maven вершина иерархии пакетов находится в папке `src/main/java`. Если ваш класс `Main` лежит в `src/main/java/Main.java`, то он находится в корневом пакете. То есть, в `pom.xml` на него можно ссылаться как `Main` (а не `main.java.Main`), а в `Main.java` не должно быть строчки `package main.java;`. Аналогичная ситуация с объявлением пакета в остальных классах.

**UPDATE**

Собственно, то, что я написал выше, и есть решение вашей проблемы, просто вы его его как-то выборочно применили. Ещё раз: `main.java` не является частью иерархии пакетов. Это стандартная папка с исходниками приложения, с которой эта иерархия и начинается. У вас же в каждом классе есть объявление `package main.java`, хотя ни один ваших из классов в этом пакете не находится. Например, класс `Solution` в вашем коде объявлен как находящийся в пакете `main.java.Functions.FunctionsSolutions`, хотя по факту он находится в пакете `Functions.FunctionsSolutions`. Исправьте пакеты всех классов, поправьте импорты, и классы начнут видеть друг друга.

И ещё совет не по теме: в Git обычно хранят только исходники. Там не должно быть ничего, что другой разработчик не смог бы получить самостоятельно, скомпилировав проект. То есть, ни скомпилированных классов (папки `out` и `target`, их можно получить, скомпилировав проект), ни библиотек (папка `lib`, её содержимое должен скачивать Maven) в Git быть не должно. Также обычно в Git не хранят настройки IDE (папка `.idea`, файлы `*.iml`). Их можно исключить из контроля версий при помощи файла `.gitignore`.

Comment: Не помогло, idea говорит мне что все классы вообще находятся не в самом проекте((( как будто их вообще там нет.

Comment: Проверьте, помечена ли папка `java` как папка с исходниками. В дереве проекта кликните по ней правой кнопкой и выберите Mark Directory As -> Sources Root. Если какая-нибудь другая папка помечена как Sources Root (синяя папка в дереве), то отмените эту пометку (Mark Directory As -> Unmark as Sources Root).

Comment: Да она голубого цвета была и есть.Извините, если вам не трудно будет, можно я вам дам ссылку с проектом на Github? Если у вас конечно есть время и вас это не затруднит. Просто мне проект учитель сказал сдать до завтра ему, а я его собрать в jar файл не могу( вот https://github.com/Mircella/least_squares_method

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, Вы так помогли. Все запустилось. Спасибо за совет насчет Git - я просто только недавно начала изучать программирование, поэтому таких вещей еще не знала. Еще раз большое спасибо. Удачи Вам!

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, что отвлекаю. Все запускается, только файлы fxml нет, их не надо как-то прописать в pom.xml? или их над обязательно в папке res держать?

Comment: Две проблемы. Во-первых, файлы ресурсов (а это все файлы, которые не `*.java`) должны лежать не в папке `src`, а в соседней папке `resources` (у вас её нет; когда создадите - не забудьте её в IDEA пометить как Resources Root). Во-вторых, в ваших `*.fxml` файлах всё ещё есть ссылки на пакеты `main.java`, их нужно вычистить.

Comment: Еще раз большое Вам спасибо, очень признательна Вам за помощь. Удачного дня!